# How to open "Performance Options" dialog from command line or system call

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to automatically open up the Windows "Performance Options" dialog using the command line or a system call?

The long way to get there is to go to Start, right-click on "Computer", choose "Properties", then select "Advanced System Settings".

A slightly shorter way is to go to Start, type in "Adjust", then select the "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows" option. I am hoping for a batch file I could run or a simple EXE I could create that would open this dialog up directly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144191(VS.85).aspx#other_commands) you are looking for:

```
%windir%\system32\SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe
```

Comment: This is handy to keep as a symlink on your desktop if you want to not run too much heavy graphics. I found just two settings made me happy enough not to run any more.

Comment: `mklink %userprofile%\desktop\systempropertiesperformance.exe %windir%\system32\systempropertiesperformance.exe` should achieve the above.